# The function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$. For any interval in $[-1,1]$, there are always both positive and negative values of $f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

The function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$. For any interval in $[-1,1]$, there are always both positive and negative values of $f(x)$. How can I prove that $\int^1_{-1}f=0$? I think that given the conditions we can say there is some $x$ with $f(x)=0$ in any interval, but I'm stuck from here...

Comment: take $f(x)=x^2$ then $f$ is $\Bbb R$ integrable but $\int f\neq 0$

Comment: There are always both positive and negative values of f(x), for ANY interval in [-1,1],

Comment: You say "I think that given the conditions we can say there is some $x$ with $f(x)=0$  in any interval."  You are right both that this is true and also that this would immediately supply a proof.  In more advanced courses you learn that every integrable function is almost everywhere continuous, consequently a function that assumes $+$ and $-$ values in every interval is zero at every point of continuity and hence almost everywhere equal to zero.   But I can't see how for the moment how to prove this at an elementary level.  So the answer from Nitin is best possible and completely elementary.

Answer (score 6):

Let $P$ be any partition of $[-1,1]$. Since $f$ contains positive values on every interval, the upper sum $U(P,f)$ is positive. Hence
$$\int f = \inf\limits_{P} U(P,f) \geq 0.$$
Similarly, $L(P,f)$ is negative, so that 
$$\int f = \sup\limits_{P} L(P,f) \leq 0.$$
A more interesting question, which I am unsure of the answer for, is whether there is such a function that is Riemann integrable.

Comment: You can construct such a function, say, by taking the Popcorn function and making sure to have negative values at enough of the rational points.  It will be bounded, zero and continuous at all irrationals and hence integrable.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I was thinking of a variant of the popcorn function but couldn't fully justify the "enough rational points" part. I was considering this:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0& x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \\    \frac{1}{2n} & x = \frac{p}{2n} \\ -\frac{1}{2n+1} & x = \frac{p}{2n+1}\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

I tend to view questions from students as an opportunity to cram some further instruction in (not unlike the way that
Strasbourgers treat their geese).  That may or not work on StackExchange which, so far, seems to me often a free homework consulting service.  The students
here may just want to hand it in, not waste time upvoting or seeing more discussion.

Anyway ...  Let's review this problem along with a few similar ones.

> **Problem A**. Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.  Suppose
>   that every subinterval of $[a,b]$ contains a point at which $f$ is
>   zero.  Show that $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=0$.
>
> **Problem B**. Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.  Suppose
>   that every subinterval of $[a,b]$ contains a point  at which $f$ is
>   positive as well as a point  at which $f$ is negative.  Show that
>   $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=0$.
>
> **Problem C**. Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Show
>   that every subinterval of $[a,b]$ contains a point  at which $f$ is
>   continuous.
>
> **Problem D**. Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ with
>   $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,dt$.  Show that every subinterval of $[a,b]$
>   contains a point $x$ at which $F'(x)=f(x)$.
>
> **Problem E**. Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ with
>   $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,dt$.  Show that, if $F$ is strictly increasing,
>   then every subinterval of $[a,b]$ contains a point $x$ at which
>   $F'(x)>0$.
>
> **Problem F**. Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and that
>   $\int_c^d f(t)\,dt=0$ for all $c$, $d$.  Show that    every
>   subinterval of $[a,b]$ contains a point $x$ at which $f(x)=0$.

*From an elementary point of view*:  Problems A and B are immediate merely from the definition.  For any partition of
$[a,b]$ there is a Riemann sum that is exactly zero (for A)
or there are two Riemann sums, one positive and one negative (for B) hence the value of the integral (which is assumed to exist) must be zero in both cases.  The remaining problems are not so obvious.

*From an advanced point of view*: All six problems are identical.
We always think of Riemann integrable functions as being almost everywhere continuous.  Both A and B say that $f$ is almost everywhere zero (since it is zero at points of continuity), so of course a zero integral.  Problem C says the points of continuity are dense, but of course they are.  Problem D says that, since $F'=f$ at points of continuity, of course there are such points.  Problem E says that, if there are no points with $F'(x)>0$ then $F'(x)=f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.  Etc.

Our elementary students have been handicapped by the habit that textbook writers have (guilty myself of course) of not supplying them with any indication that Riemann integrable functions must be *quite* continuous.   Lebesgue's characterization is too advanced so ... well leave it to later.

Here is a modest proposal.  Teach elementary analysis students at least this useful (if weak) lemma:

> **Lemma** Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Then every subinterval of $[a,b]$ contains a point  at which $f$ is
>   continuous.
>
> **Proof**.  We use $\omega_f(x)$ to denote the usual oscillation of
>   $f$ at the point $x$, i.e., 
>    $$\omega_f(x)=
>  \inf_{\delta>0}\sup\{|f(v)-f(u)|: u, v \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)\}).$$
>   This function is continuous at a point $x$ if and only if 
>   $\omega_f(x)=0$.  The only integration theory we need here is the
>   observation that if  $\omega_f(x)> k >0$ for all $x$ in an interval
>   $[c,d]$ then $f$ cannot be integrable on $[c,d]$.  The reason is that
>   the difference between the upper sums and the lower  sum would be
>   larger than $k(d-c)$.
>
> Now use a simple nested interval argument. Take any subinterval
>   $[a_0,b_0]$ of $[a,b]$.  There must be a point $x_0$ in this interval
>   so that $\omega_f(x_0)<1$  (otherwise $f$ would not be integrable on
>   $[a_0,b_0]$). But if    $\omega_f(x_0)<1$ then there must be an
>   interval $[a_1,b_1]$ containing $x_0$ so that all points $x$ of that
>   interval also satisfy $\omega_f(x)<1$.
>
> Thus, inductively, we can construct a nested sequence of intervals
>   $[a_n,b_n]$ so that all points $x$ of the interval  $[a_n,b_n]$ must 
>   satisfy $\omega_f(x)<\frac 1n$.   There is a point $z$ in all of the
>   intervals and for that  point $\omega_f(z)<\frac 1n$ for all $n$,
>   meaning that $\omega_f(z)=0$.  There is our point of continuity inside
>   $[a_0,b_0]$! ...QED.
>
> The proof is not too long and uses only the main features of any
>   elementary real analysis course, namely continuity and a nested
>   interval arguments.

[Aside: the advanced student will recognize that there is a category argument being used   covertly.  The set of discontinuity points of a Riemann integrable function must be both measure zero and first category.  We are avoiding measure arguments, and so we are instead substituting a category argument to obtain a dense set of points of continuity.]